# Login failure in jbpm-console jboss-as-7

Tags: jboss7.x, jbpm, kie

I have a problem with the jbpm-console, generated to source , I installed jbpm-console-ng-jboss-as7.0.war in jboss, that deploy OK, config security-domain in the subsystem "urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1" and add users and roles properties , in the standalone, create the jboss user, but when login to jbpm-console, I have the following error `Login failed: Not Authorized`

The security-dommain is that in standalone.xml :

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
        <security-domains>
            ...
            <security-domain name="jbpm-console-ng" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```

The roles.properties you content is that :

```
root=jbpm-console-user,user,analyst,PM,IT,Reviewer
```

The users.properties you content is that :

```
root=root
```

The jboss user is "root".

Help me plis !!

Comment: check the file  <EAP-x.x\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties>, set user=admin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your security-domain is being referenced in jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>jbpm-console-ng</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

this file is on jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml